# Django - Get objects from the table which do not have a Foreignkey in another table

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I am Django rest framework to return the list of objects who do not have a foreign key in another table. what queryset should I write to get those objects.

```
models.py


    class Event(models.Model):
      id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
      title = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
      description = models.TextField(blank=True,default='', max_length=1000)
      link = models.URLField(null=True)
      image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
      organizer = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
      timings = models.DateTimeField(default=None)
      cost = models.IntegerField(default=1,null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Featured(models.Model):

       event = models.ForeignKey(Event, null=True ,on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="event")

      def __str__(self):
          return self.event.title
    
      class Meta:
          verbose_name_plural = 'Featured'
```

```
views.py

      class Upcoming2EventsViewSet(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,mixins.ListModelMixin,viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = Upcoming2Events
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        featured_events = Featured.objects.all().values_list('id')
        return Event.objects.filter(id__in=featured_events)
        # return Event.objects.exclude(id__in=featured_events.event.id)
        # # return Event.objects.exclude(id__in = [featured_events.id])
```

```
serializers.py

class Upcoming2Events(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.CharField(source='event.id')
    title = serializers.CharField(source='event.title')
    timings = serializers.DateTimeField(source='event.timings')
    organizer = serializers.CharField(source='event.organizer')
    class Meta:
        model = Featured
        fields = ['id','title','organizer','timings']
```

```
Error

Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `id` on serializer `Upcoming2Events`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Event` instance.
Original exception text was: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'id'.
```

Can you tell me what queryset should I write to get the only objects which are not present in the table Featured?

Also, what should I do to get only the upcoming 2 events from the Event table which are not present in the Featured table?

> Note I am not supposed to use any flag value, can you provide some other solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the Informations you wrote here, i would suggest using a flag to determine a featured event. A second Model is useful if you want to provide more Informations on this specific for a featured event

like this:

```py
class Event(models.Model):
      id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
      title = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
      description = models.TextField(blank=True,default='', max_length=1000)
      link = models.URLField(null=True)
      image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
      organizer = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
      timings = models.DateTimeField(default=None)
      cost = models.IntegerField(default=1,null=True,blank=True)
      featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

so you can directly use querysets to get what you want:

```py
Event.objects.exclude(featured=True)

Event.objects.exclude(featured=True).order_by('-timings')[:2]
```

I would use ModelViewsets directly, hence you will use your model here.
views and serializers would look like this:

views.py

```py
class Upcoming2EventsViewSet(viewesets.ReadyOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = EventSerializer
    queryset = Event.objects.exclude(featured=True).order_by('-timings')[:2]
```

serializers.py

```py
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerilizer):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'organizer', 'timings']
```

As improvement i would provide filters instead of setting up different ViewSets for just filtering querysets.

Comment: hey, thanks for the solution but actually I'm not supposed to use any flag value. is there any other way to do it?

Comment: then the only other way is to use a nested serializer like mentioned here https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

but i would try to convince whoever doesn't like the flag that its in this case de best solution - if you don't have custom fields on Featured Events like mentioned above